# Reduce CSS layout and repaint for variable font animation

Tags: css, fonts, css-animations, variable-fonts

I'm trying variable font animation following [this tutorial](https://css-irl.info/variable-font-animation-with-css-and-splitting-js/). However, I have noticed a heavy CPU overhead in this animation (especially in rendering):

[image]

Comparing with a similar benchmark result but with transform animation:

[image]

So if it's possible to layout and repaint for variable font animation such that this animation can have much better performance?

Here is an example:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans Roman";
  src: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/85648/IBMPlexSansVar-Roman.ttf");
}

.animation {
  width: 8rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans Roman";
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 100, 'wdth' 85;
  text-align: center;
  animation: breathe 4000ms infinite both;
}

@keyframes breathe {
  0% {
    font-variation-settings: 'wght' 100, 'wdth' 85;
  }

  60% {
    font-variation-settings: 'wght' 700, 'wdth' 100;
  }

  100% {
    font-variation-settings: 'wght' 100, 'wdth' 85;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation">G</div>
```

Comment: When animating a variable font, many different instances of the font will be selected and rendered, each requiring hundreds of calculations to derive the glyph outlines for that instance before they can be rasterized. In a repeating pattern, if the same instances were selected, the browser could cache the results for each instance. But that assumes the same instances get selected on each pass. Maybe inserting extra keyframes would increase the chance that instances will get re-used, though it's up to the browser to cache.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to address the underlying problem, as that's up to the browser. One workaround is to animate in steps, and find a value that's low, but still produces a smooth animation:

```css
animation: breathe 4000ms infinite both steps(40);
```

This will produce a maximum of 40 "versions" of your font for all keyframes, as opposed to possible thousands.